# Pandas - Concat multiindex with single index

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
                Qty
Year    Month
2017    Jan     1
        Feb     2
2016    Jan     7
        Feb     4
```

and `df.groupby(level = 0).sum()` gives me this:

```
        Qty
Year
2017    3
2016    11
```

and I want to produce this:

```
                Qty
Year    Month
2017    Jan     1
        Feb     2
2017 Total      3
2016    Jan     7
        Feb     4
2016 Total      11
```

Where the value of the  `Month` index is an empty string. `concat` doesn't quit work how I want, it gives:

```
               Qty
(2017, Jan)    1
(2017, Feb)    2
(2016, Jan)    7
(2016, Feb)    4
2017           3
2016           11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [59]: df.append(df.groupby(level=0).sum().reset_index().assign(Month='Total') \
        .set_index(['Year','Month'])) \
        .sort_index()
Out[59]:
            Qty
Year Month
2016 Feb      4
     Jan      7
     Total   11
2017 Feb      2
     Jan      1
     Total    3
```